# How to export below image graph from pixels to millimeters?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, pixel, converters, drop

A linear graph of the drop curve is taken from this image, but the graph is too large because it is in pixels, it is necessary to convert the graph data in Mathematica to millimeters.

[Drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnxka.png)

[Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUnY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get started

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnxka.png"];

img // RemoveBackground // AlphaChannel // EdgeDetect // Thinning // 
 ImageMesh[#, Method -> "MarchingSquares"] & // Show[#, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 500] &
```

[image]

You can use the `DataRange` option to `ImageMesh` to shift/scale the values as needed.